# What is the "ROS and Gazebo Migration" account doing?

Tags: discussion, ros-migration, specific-question, users

[What is this question?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23874/wheels-look-sliding-instead-of-rotating)

From the question,

> Originally posted by amine23 on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-08
>
> Post score: 0

The same user, [ROS and Gazebo Migration](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/32603/ros-and-gazebo-migration), then posts the answer, which includes:

> Originally posted by nkoenig with karma: 7661 on 2013-04-10
>
> Post score: 0

**So my question is  this:** Why is someone reposting a zero-score question, from a user with 5 karma, with a zero-score answer, to our site? What value does this add to our site, and should we expect more of this to happen in the future?

Comment: Wow I thought the comments on the question were in response to something else someone deleted, but nope, they're straight from the [original question on the gazebosim forums](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2273/wheels-look-sliding-instead-of-rotating/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the noise. This is a test, we'll have more information to announce soon. Expect to see some posts being made and deleted from this account for the moment. Unfortunately we don't have a sandbox to test using the Stack Exchange API.

---

Update:

I have some exciting news for you. We’re planning to migrate ROS Answer and Gazebo Answers here. We’ve been working with Stack Overflow to get this setup. And some of you have noticed a few tests going on.

We’re working on making this migration as painless as possible but there’s definitely going to be some noise as things are migrated. The end result will be that there will be a lot more awesome ROS content in the Robotics Stack Exchange.

In the migration we are going to be looking to only migrate the content with valuable results. To that end we will be applying heuristics such as only questions with an accepted answer or with one more upvoted answer.

We will be creating tag mappings between the two sites to make sure that we can cleanly migrate  everything over and homogenize tags in the process. We’ll also be  trimming away any tags which are not commonly used to avoid noise.

The postings will include a small citation block pointing to the original content with attribution. If you have an account on both sides of the migration we will be looking to link your usernames and provide direct attribution as well. We’re also working with Stack Overflow to backdate the content appropriately.

Re: the bot account and it's karma level. After the migration is completed the migration account will be disabled. And with the support of Stack Overflow teams attributable content will be reattributed.

### New traffic

After the migration ROS Answers and Gazebo Answers will be left online in read only mode for some period of time. Users will be directed here to ask new questions instead of ROS Answers. Those users redirected here will greatly increase the volume of activity on this site. I have asked the existing moderators to look at getting involved here and earn karma naturally. There have definitely been some here already, however it’s hard to earn karma quickly without higher question volumes. There will definitely be a lot of new users and we ask for your help in teaching them the ropes. My understanding of the statistics is that the traffic may go up by about an order of magnitude. Stack Exchange has much better moderation and review tools and I hope that we will be able to support the community better here even as we educate people about the Stack Exchange way of doing things.

If you have something that you’d like to reach out to us about that’s not appropriate for a public forum you can reach the team working on the migration at answers-se-migration@openrobotics.org

For reference I've [announced this on ROS Discourse too](https://discourse.ros.org/t/planned-migration-of-ros-answers-and-gazebo-answers-to-robotics-stack-exchange/28068?u=tfoote)

Comment: Can you share any details now? Reading this I'm worried I'll log in one day and find 10k posts copy/pasted from ROS forums, or worse to find every day is a new 100 posts copy/pasted. I just don't want the little traffic we do have to get lost in a tidal wave of migrating posts. I'm also curious if everything is coming over or if the Q&A will be curated somehow. Gotta say, it's really disheartening to see a zero-score question with a zero-score answer come across as the first migrated post.

Comment: There is an API sandbox on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox where you can post answers. If that works, questions is a matter of adding a title and tags.

Comment: I've already flagged them as spam. I think the more information you mentioned needs to be included in the post.

Comment: The profile for that "user" could include that it is a test. And say where that magic 1000 rep came from. It dismayingly undercuts the intended gamification of that score.

Comment: I've updated the answer above with our announcement. And the profile of the user with links to here and the ROS Discourse announcement.