# Can/should questions on Stack Overflow about ROS be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration, questions

There are a lot of them: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ros

I tried flagging a recent one for movement here, but there's no checkbox for movement so an explanation has to be put in (I added a link to [What is the "ROS and Gazebo Migration" account doing?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/what-is-the-ros-and-gazebo-migration-account-doing) to help explain it).  It would be a ton of work to manually flag many of the old questions and for moderators to actually move them- maybe just new ones going forward?

Also asked same thing on ros discourse https://discourse.ros.org/t/planned-migration-of-ros-answers-and-gazebo-answers-to-robotics-stack-exchange/28068/19

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, No.

With the stack exchange network, there is a limited time period within which any migration is possible, before it is locked to a site. If it isn't migrated soon enough, or an incorrect migration isn't rejected soon enough, a question can easily end up 'stuck' on the 'wrong' site.

Arguably though, if a question has a highly voted, accepted answer, was it really in the wrong place in the first place? While we would like all ROS questions to come here, we have no right to expect it. We can't just gather up questions from stack overflow and have people redirected here, we have to become the go-to place for ROS questions by our own merits. Once getting a ROS answer here is quicker and more reliable than getting one on Stackoverflow, we may be able to justify *Robotics* as a suitable migration path, but that may sound easier than it is, in practice.

Essentially, I'm more than happy to welcome any and all roboticists who want to ask ROS questions to ask them here, but I don't want to achieve that by taking questions from another site in the network.

The situation with ROS.answers is entirely different, and I'm glad to see things progressing there. As a *Robotics* moderator, I haven't had much to do with that migration. We were consulted, of course, but most of the work has been done staff members, with our encouragement.

Personally, I'm really looking forward to the potential of our combined communities.

Incidentally, There is already a mention of *Robotics* in the [ros tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ros) over on Stack Overflow, and I'll happily edit that to mention ROS and Gazebo Answers when the migration is complete, and people have had a little time to settle in. Hopefully that will make it even more likely that people will chose to answer here rather than on SO.

Comment: "if a question has a highly voted, accepted answer, was it really in the wrong place in the first place" - what about zero votes and no answers or comments?

Comment: If a question has zero votes and no answers or comments, then I would question it's value. *8')

Comment: Seriously though, new questions always have potential for migration, it's only old questions which are locked in place that can't be migrated. In this case I would suggest commenting on the question along the lines of "This question is too old to be migrated now, but if you still need an answer, you may want to ask on [robotics.se] instead where they may be Experts who can help".